# The angle subtended by the chord containing the points B and D, at the extremity of the diameter opposite to the extremity of the chord

Tags: geometry

A circle is drawn passing through one vertex A with center at vertex C of the square
ABCD. The angle subtended by the chord containing the points B and D, at the
extremity of the diameter opposite to the extremity of the chord

MY QUERY : I didn't understand the sentence

angle  subtended  by the chord containing  the  points  B  and  D, at the
extremity of the diameter opposite to the extremity of the chord

Please help me

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding, you're supposed to find the angle subtended by chord $EF$ through $BD$, which is equivalent to $\angle ECF$. Here is a diagram (letting $P$ be the intersection of $AC$ and $EF$), with some nice lengths marked (letting $r$ be the radius of the circle):[image]

Can you solve the problem from here?

Comment: from this we get angle ECF  = 120 ( angle PCF = 60 from that angle ECF  is 120 ) but the answer given is 60

Comment: The wording of this problem is very strange, I may very well have interpreted it wrong. Does you book have a solution for this problem?